# Why do we have to use “*” while importing in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Some times while importing why do we need to use “*” 
For example :

```
import axios from 'axios'
import * as proxy from 'proxy-agent'
```

Comment: Because those modules have no default export

Comment: If there is no default , can’t we import like import {someModlue} from ‘test’

Comment: @sravankumarganji Sure, but it depends on how you want to refer to the object later on.

Comment: It's muddied by the fact that `import * as foo` in TS was a hack to allow importing CommonJS modules using ES6 syntax, though the two are not strictly compatible, whereas Babel would let you just use default `import foo`. Later `esModuleInterop` was added to TS to allow you to use `import foo` in the same way as Babel.